# has and belong to many model variable name

Tags: ruby-on-rails

So I an using rails 4 and have successfully linked my Users to my Products table using the following:

users.rb

```
  has_and_belongs_to_many :products
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :products
  # Setup accessible (or protected) attributes for your model
  attr_accessible :email, :password, :password_confirmation, :remember_me, :role_ids, :product_ids
```

products.rb

```
has_and_belongs_to_many :users
```

view/userse/_form.html.erb

```
<%= simple_form_for(@user) do |f| %>
<%= f.association :products, label: "Product Release Email", value_method: :id, :as => :check_boxes %>
```

But I would like to change the variable name :products to :productReleaseEmail I have tried changint the users.rb to

```
has_and_belongs_to_many :productReleaseEmail, :class_name => "product"
```

But I get the error "uninitialized constant User::product". So I assume I have some of my references wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Capitalize it:

```
class_name: "Product"
```